# Categorizing variable and make it a dummy in R

Tags: r, dummy-variable, categorization

Guten Tag community :)

I'm currently working with the ESGscore of some companies.
The ESGscore varies between 0 and 100.

I want to categorize the ESGscore into 4 segments:

```
0 - 25 --> poor --> 4
>25 - 50 --> medium --> 3
>50 - 75 --> good --> 2
75 - 100 --> excellent --> 1
```

The problem with `dummy.code` is that it is rearranging the ESGscore. So for example the ESGscore of the *AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC* is always 'excellent' but the output shows me, that it is just medium.

This is what the **CODE** looks like:

```
Datensatz_final_so$ESG.Kategorien <- ifelse(Datensatz_final_so$ESGscore <= 25, "4",
                                            ifelse(Datensatz_final_so$ESGscore > 25 & Datensatz_final_so$ESGscore <= 50, "3",
                                                   ifelse(Datensatz_final_so$ESGscore > 50 & Datensatz_final_so$ESGscore <= 75, "2",
                                                          ifelse(Datensatz_final_so > 75, "1", 0))))``
    # Create ESGscore dummy #
    Dummy.ESG <- dummy.code(Datensatz_final_so$ESG.Kategorien)

colnames(Dummy.ESG) <- c("poor", "medium", "good", "excellent")

# Connect data and dummy #
Datensatz_final <- cbind(Datensatz_final, Dummy.ESG)
```

Do you know how to fix that?

One way is to rearrange `colnames` to

```
colnames(Dummy.ESG) <- c("good", "excellent", "poor", "medium")
```

but it is creating the problem, that R picks medium for reference in the analysis.

Thank you in advance! :)

**DATA EXAMPLE:**

```
    structure(list(Company = c("AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC", "AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC", 
"AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC", "AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC", 
"AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC", "AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC", 
"AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC", "HESS CORP", "HESS CORP", "HESS CORP", 
"HESS CORP", "HESS CORP", "HESS CORP", "HESS CORP", "APACHE CORP", 
"APACHE CORP", "APACHE CORP", "APACHE CORP", "APACHE CORP", "APACHE CORP", 
"APACHE CORP", "AVERY DENNISON CORP", "AVERY DENNISON CORP", 
"AVERY DENNISON CORP", "AVERY DENNISON CORP", "AVERY DENNISON CORP", 
"AVERY DENNISON CORP", "AVERY DENNISON CORP", "BALL CORP", "BALL CORP", 
"BALL CORP", "BALL CORP", "BALL CORP", "BALL CORP", "BALL CORP", 
"CHEVRON CORP", "CHEVRON CORP", "CHEVRON CORP", "CHEVRON CORP", 
"CHEVRON CORP", "CHEVRON CORP", "CHEVRON CORP", "ECOLAB INC", 
"ECOLAB INC", "ECOLAB INC", "ECOLAB INC", "ECOLAB INC", "ECOLAB INC", 
"ECOLAB INC", "EXXON MOBIL CORP", "EXXON MOBIL CORP", "EXXON MOBIL CORP", 
"EXXON MOBIL CORP", "EXXON MOBIL CORP", "EXXON MOBIL CORP", "EXXON MOBIL CORP", 
"FMC CORP", "FMC CORP", "FMC CORP", "FMC CORP", "FMC CORP", "FMC CORP", 
"FMC CORP", "HALLIBURTON CO", "HALLIBURTON CO", "HALLIBURTON CO", 
"HALLIBURTON CO", "HALLIBURTON CO", "HALLIBURTON CO", "HALLIBURTON CO", 
"HELMERICH & PAYNE", "HELMERICH & PAYNE", "HELMERICH & PAYNE", 
"HELMERICH & PAYNE", "HELMERICH & PAYNE", "HELMERICH & PAYNE", 
"HELMERICH & PAYNE"), Year = c(2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 
2016, 2017, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2011, 2012, 
2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 
2017, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2011, 2012, 2013, 
2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 
2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 
2015, 2016, 2017, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2011, 
2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017), gvkey = c(1209, 1209, 1209, 
1209, 1209, 1209, 1209, 1380, 1380, 1380, 1380, 1380, 1380, 1380, 
1678, 1678, 1678, 1678, 1678, 1678, 1678, 1913, 1913, 1913, 1913, 
1913, 1913, 1913, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 2991, 
2991, 2991, 2991, 2991, 2991, 2991, 4213, 4213, 4213, 4213, 4213, 
4213, 4213, 4503, 4503, 4503, 4503, 4503, 4503, 4503, 4510, 4510, 
4510, 4510, 4510, 4510, 4510, 5439, 5439, 5439, 5439, 5439, 5439, 
5439, 5581, 5581, 5581, 5581, 5581, 5581, 5581), ESGscore = c(84.2750015258789, 
81.9225006103516, 77.4024963378906, 80.1125030517578, 78.6449966430664, 
76.3775024414062, 79.2699966430664, 69.4899978637695, 65.8300018310547, 
64.4300003051758, 74.3000030517578, 75.7600021362305, 71.4599990844727, 
74.6900024414062, 55.8300018310547, 56.0900001525879, 57.5, 60.75, 
60.8800010681152, 67.379997253418, 71.9899978637695, 82.9000015258789, 
77.3899993896484, 76.9300003051758, 78.7399978637695, 76.2283325195312, 
74.2125015258789, 68.3600006103516, 64.4100036621094, 65.6600036621094, 
63.75, 67.7300033569336, 67.5699996948242, 74.4300003051758, 
68.5699996948242, 86.5100021362305, 84.3099975585938, 82.6600036621094, 
82.3399963378906, 88.4100036621094, 90.0800018310547, 92.25, 
74.6999969482422, 72.3600006103516, 68.3899993896484, 67.9300003051758, 
65.629997253418, 74.9000015258789, 74.8600006103516, 81.6999969482422, 
79.370002746582, 79.0899963378906, 75.25, 81.9499969482422, 81.0199966430664, 
88.3399963378906, 59.8199996948242, 55.6500015258789, 52.2999992370605, 
51.8499984741211, 56.9199981689453, 66.620002746582, 65.3300018310547, 
85.9800033569336, 83.9499969482422, 85.1100006103516, 67.4300003051758, 
76.4400024414062, 69.9199981689453, 78.4599990844727, 19.0599994659424, 
17.5200004577637, 18.1200008392334, 23.5025005340576, 35.5349998474121, 
36.7350006103516, 41.1725006103516)), row.names = c(NA, -77L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Where does this `dummy.code` come from? Is this your function? Perhaps you could show what the function is doing? Are you using `cut()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample data does not include a variable called `ESG.Kategorien` but it does include `ESGscore`. The following should give you what you want:

```
Datensatz_final_so$Dummy <- cut(Datensatz_final_so$ESGscore, breaks=c(0, 25, 50, 75, 100), labels=c("poor", "medium", "good", "excellent"))
table(Datensatz_final_so$Dummy)
# 
#      poor    medium      good excellent 
#         4         3        38        32 
levels(Datensatz_final_so$Dummy)
# [1] "poor"      "medium"    "good"      "excellent"
```

Note your original categorization places 75 in good AND excellent.

Comment: That's totally right, I forgotsomething, please check the question again.

Comment: Thank you very much, @dcarlson :)
How would I select the breaks for a sector dummy variable, if I only would have two numbers numbers?
Sector 1 = 1010
Sector 2 = 1510

Comment: If there are only two numbers, `Sector <- ifelse(Number==1010, "Sector 1", "Sector 2")`, but that will only work reliably if `Number` is an integer variable. With `cut` you could set the `breaks=c(0, 1010, 1510)`.

Comment: Thank you very much @dcarlson! It is working perfectly and you've helped me a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's take your data as df:

```r
df<- structure(
  list(
    Company = c(
      "AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC",
      ...
      ...
  ),
  row.names = c(NA,-77L),
  class = c("tbl_df",
            "tbl", "data.frame")
)
```

lets take categories and build a small dataframe, then a bit of `dplyr`

```
ESG <- c("poor", "medium", "good", "excellent")
da <- data.frame(ESGColumn = 1:4,FlatESG = ESG)

df <- df |> dplyr::mutate(ESGColumn = floor(ESGscore/25)+1) |>
  dplyr::left_join(da, by="ESGColumn") |>
  dplyr::select(-"ESGColumn")

head(df)

# A tibble: 6 × 5
  Company                       Year gvkey ESGscore FlatESG  
  <chr>                        <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>    
1 AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC  2011  1209     84.3 excellent
2 AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC  2012  1209     81.9 excellent
3 AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC  2013  1209     77.4 excellent
4 AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC  2014  1209     80.1 excellent
5 AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC  2015  1209     78.6 excellent
6 AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC  2016  1209     76.4 excellent
```

Grzegorz

Comment: Thank you very much, @Grzegorz. :)